# apache redirect to redirectUrl in query string

Tags: apache

I have a request like:

http://www.example.com/test?redirectUrl=http://www.test.com

I want apache to use the `redirectUrl` param and redirect to `http://www.test.com`

The redirectUrl may be any valid url. like:

http://www.test.com/a/b?x=1&y=2&url=some_encoded_url

How should I config apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got some answer myself:

```
  RewriteMap unescape int:unescape

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(https?[^&\ ]+)
  RewriteRule ^/share ${unescape:%1} [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=((https?){0}[^&\ ]+)
  RewriteRule ^/share http://${unescape:%1} [R,L]
```